# Question in Triage is a duplicate, but the master question has no upvoted answers—what do I do?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, triage

I recently got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996154/php-fatal-error-cannot-use-try-without-catch-or-finally) in the Triage queue. A quick Google of the error message immediately found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983915/fatal-error-cannot-use-try-without-catch-or-finally-in-users-xxx-www-index-php) posted ~2 years ago. It has 3 answers, but because neither of them were upvoted or accepted I couldn't mark it as a duplicate.

The question in triage has since been answered with the first answer accepted, but *before that happened* I wonder what would've been the most appropriate action to take.

Should a similar situation arise in the future, would it be better to upvote one of the answers on the older question so it can be marked as `Unsalvageable > a duplicate...`, or would a different flag be more appropriate?

Comment: The "n" without the back slash the strong correspondance in text there might be some heavy copy past involved here. Maybe plagia.

Comment: @DragandDrop most probably copied from [here](https://stackify.com/php-try-catch-php-exception-tutorial/), one of the answerer might have corrected the missing backslashes from the source..

Comment: There must be an other better dupe target. I just got lost on [php] without finding one and don't wan't to go again.

Comment: If I were a subject expert, and there is a good answer on that question I'd upvote it and use it as a dupe target.

Comment: @Kaddath Good catch! Didn't notice that. Looks like the accepted answer has a direct copy, while one of the answers on master question was modified to fix the `\n`

Comment: look like a borderline typo to me. Time for php experts to step in.

Comment: Are both not just off-topic as 'Questions seeking debugging help must...." ?

Comment: I think you can trigger the flag despite in one there is already an answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I agree both are probably off-topic on the grounds that *the error message answers itself*. I also see somebody's upvoted answers in the original 2017 question though, so for now I've submitted an edit to cleanup the question's code and marked the triaged one as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are confident that it's a duplicate, hopefully you're knowledgeable enough on the subject to tell whether the existing answers on the target are helpful and/or correct. If you find some that are, upvote them, and then you can mark the question as a dupe of the target.

If you're not sure, consider that this is by design... if a question exists with answers but none are upvoted, *ideally* you can trust that the system *writ large* has found those answers wanting (hence their non-positive score)... and an abandoned question with no useful answers is not a good dupe target, so the right thing to do *is* to ask the new question...

You may not be able to handle this *within* the Triage review system... it might not detect that the question has a new upvote without refreshing (I'm not sure). If that's the case, you can just <kbd>Skip</kbd> the review item and flag/close it as a duplicate manually to make sure the suggestion is stored by the system.

In this scenario, you could/should go and mark the older question as a duplicate of the newer one, since the newer one has an answer that is upvoted (if the answer also answers the older question, which it should if these two questions are duplicates). This will prevent this same scenario happening in the future when other people ask the same question and reviewers find that original duplicate target with no upvoted answers.